# Where is netherite?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Alright so...
I cannot find netherite on Xbox One or Xbox 360. I have done all the updates and it still not up to date. I have a friend with Minecraft and he has netherite and more updated stuff. Im wondering if my Xbox is broken, or netherite is only supported on certain platforms. If so, which ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netherite is actually an unreleased update. I don't know about Xbox but it is a snapshot. You have to use experimental gameplay and if on PC java edition, it is easier. So far, on your edition, which is the most current one, it is normal to not have netherite. Don't worry, and hope for Mojang to release their update sooner.

Answer (score 0):

Netherite is already available and you can find it around `y = 15`. Best you can use to find netherite faster is explosives.

The best explosive for the nether are beds. Very cheap, and makes a huge explosion, giving you a higher chance of finding ancient debris. You also need to mine gold and smelt the debris for netherite scraps.

Make the netherite ingots and get a smithing table, then start upgrading your diamond items. Now you have netherite!